# Do I need alert dialog for accessing location when I have location permissions in Manifest and why I am getting this error for alert dialog?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am building an app where I am using locations. And I have declared permission in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Do I now need to make alert dialog to make that user enables permission for location on his device, or I have done that with this permission in manifest?
When I made dialog for turning GPS on I am getting this error:

```
09-14 12:18:12.614 28114-28114/com.telnet.asp E/WindowManager: Activity com.telnet.asp.presentation.view.activities.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42b29910 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-720,351} that was originally added here
                                                               android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.telnet.asp.presentation.view.activities.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42b29910 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-720,351} that was originally added here
                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java)
                                                                   at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java)
                                                                   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java)
                                                                   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java)
                                                                   at com.telnet.asp.presentation.view.activities.MainActivity.showDialogForAllowingLocation(MainActivity.java:380)
                                                                   at com.telnet.asp.presentation.view.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:63)
                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java)
                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And this is my alert dialog:

```
 private void showDialogForAllowingLocation() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.enable_permission));
        builder.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.enable_access));
        builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
        builder.setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.enable), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                startActivity(
                        new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.ignore), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
    private void EnableGPSIfPossible() {
        final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            showDialogForAllowingLocation();
        }
    }
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: You have to add dialog to prompt user to on GPS if phone GPS is off.

Comment: Please see edited question.

Comment: Yes if the targetSdkVersion  iis equal or greater than  23 and the phone uses Android M or above  -- check here on how to it -- https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en -- otherwise when you download an app below 23 with a phone below Android M it will ask to grant for the permission  before you install the App

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This make sure that your app will run without breaking. Check the Internet connection and gps before the app start.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the user has GPS turned on, if not, then you have to show the prompt dialog.

However, note that starting with Android 6.0 (API 23) you have to manually ask the user to grant the permission, because `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` is categorized as dangerous. More info on permission groups here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html

Answer (score 0):

> Yes you need to runtime permission for Android 6.0 or greater follow that

```
 private static final int REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION = 123;


    if (CheckPermission(demo.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {


        showDialogForAllowingLocation();

    } else {
        // you do not have permission go request runtime permissions
        RequestPermission(demo.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION);
    }



public void RequestPermission(Activity thisActivity, String Permission, int Code) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Permission)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
                    Permission)) {
                showDialogForAllowingLocation();

            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                        new String[]{Permission},
                        Code);
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean CheckPermission(Activity context, String Permission) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                Permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use permission designed for `android version > L`

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
                (this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
                        (this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            }, 1);

        }
```

Permission handling:

```
 @Override
 public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull   String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
switch (requestCode) {

    case 1:
        if (grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            //do something
        }
    default:
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
 }
}
```